# Why does event remain null even after subscribing to it?

Tags: c#, events

I have classes Room and Iceball. Iceball and IceShard are inherited from class Magic.
When I add new magic to room, room subscribes to event CreateNewMagic magic, but after exiting from method event is still null.

Iceball after collision should creates ice shards in the room with the help of event, but because the event is null room cant spawn ice shards

Class Room

```
{
    public readonly List<Magi> MagicInRoom;
    public void SpawnMagic(Magic magic)
        {
            MagicInRoom.Add(magic);
            magic.CreateNewMagic += SpawnMagic;
        }
}
```

Class Magic, IceBall and IceShard

```
public abstract class Magic
{
    public delegate void MagicHandler(Magic magic);
    public event MagicHandler CreateNewMagic;

    public virtual void OnCollisionEnter()
        {
            if (...)
                {
                ...
                }
        }
}

public class IceBall : Magic
{
    public delegate void MagicHandler(Magic magic);
    public event MagicHandler CreateNewMagic;

    public override void OnCollisionEnter()
        {
            if (...)
            {
                var iceShards = CreateIceShards();
                foreach (var iceShard in iceShards) 
                    if (CreateNewMagic != null) //ALWAYS IS NULL
                        CreateNewMagic(iceShard);
            }
        }
}

public class IceShard : Magic
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're actually working on an instance of `IceBall`, you're accessing it through the window of `Magic`, so you're subscribing to `Magic`'s `CreateNewMagic` event, not `IceBall`'s. (they are different events, and with the declaration of the delegate, they have different delegate types too). It seems you don't want the delegate or the event in `IceBall` at all, and you just want to use the event on the base class (`Magic`).

Comment: `Magic.CreateNewMagic` should be `abstract` and `IceBall.CreateNewMagic` should `override` it. Also, there is no need to define the `MagicHandler` delegate twice.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar
You right, I want use delegate on the base class Magic, but if I remove delegate and event from IceBall, I get an error <The event 'CreateNewMagic' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=>, so I don't know how solve this problem

Comment: Please show the code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Event should be abstract**

```
public abstract class Magic
{
    public delegate void MagicHandler(Magic magic);
    public abstract event MagicHandler CreateNewMagic;

    public virtual void OnCollisionEnter()
        {
            if (...)
                {
                ...
                }
        }
}

public class IceBall : Magic
{
    public override event MagicHandler CreateNewMagic;

    public override void OnCollisionEnter()
        {
            if (...)
            {
                var iceShards = CreateIceShards();
                foreach (var iceShard in iceShards) 
                    if (CreateNewMagic != null) //ALWAYS IS NULL
                        CreateNewMagic(iceShard);
            }
        }
}

public class IceShard : Magic
{
    public override event MagicHandler CreateNewMagic;
}
```